# azure api management transformation URL header using Application gateway

Tags: azure, dns, cloud, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

i have api management with in internal network with URL -  "apimgmnt.azure-api.net"  and having **API** :- **apimgmnt.azure-api.net/hello**"

also configured application gateway with url - "appgateway.cloudapp.azure.com" and access the **API** as **appgateway.cloudapp.azure.com/hello**

now i want to access this url by using "hello.appgateway.cloudapp.azure.com" which should be redirect to **apimgmnt.azure-api.net/hello**

what changes and transformation policy should i apply on api management level and application gateway url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, URL rewriting is not supported in application gateway. So, you will not be able to rewrite and access `apimgmnt.azure-api.net/hello`.

There is already a feature request on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/12239826-support-url-rewriting-with-application-gateway) for this, which is being worked on. Feel free to upvote this to gain more traction.